# Can I stream music from my laptop to my iPod Touch over wifi?

Tags: windows, audio, music, streaming, ipod-touch

Rather than running a long cable from my Laptop to my stereo, I've been thinking for a while about getting one of those wireless devices that lets you transmit audio from your PC to a receiver plugged into the stereo.

Then I realised I already have hardware that can potentially do this - I have an iPod Touch, and a Wi-Fi network in the house.

So, is there some iPod Touch App that will let the iPod act as a Wi-Fi music receiver? And presumably, a corresponding piece of broadcast software for my (Windows Vista) Laptop?

edit: Bonus points for a solution that lets me stream all audio from the laptop, rather than just streaming music tracks.

Comment: How I do this is plug my laptop into the stereo, and use the Apple Remote app to control the tunes over Wi-Fi. Works great!

Comment: Thats kinda the opposite of what I want to do. I'm trying to avoid physcially plugging my laptop into the stereo. I want to be able to move the laptop around and still have it play music through the stereo.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [the Windows version of Airfoil](http://rogueamoeba.com/airfoil/windows/) to send any audio to an Airport Express connected to a stereo.  The page above claims it can do the same via an iPod Touch as well.  And you can try it for free.

Comment: Thats exactly what I'm after. I just tried it out, it worked pretty well with a music player (Foobar2000) although it did stutter occasionally. It struggled with more processor intensive music-composition software such as Reason, and stuttered a lot. Presumably if I had a more powerful laptop, it would cut out the stuttering. Nice and easy to install and setup though. $25 for the non-demo version.

Answer (score 2):

You can also share your iTunes library on your Mac of PC and then stream your music from your computer to your iPod touch by selecting that shared iTunes library in the Music app on your iPod touch.
This solution doesn't require any extra software or app.

Answer (score 1):

On the road I use the [Simplify Media application](http://www.simplifymedia.com/) to do this. It requires an application to be installed on both the computer and the iPod touch/iPhone. Once installed I can play almost any track from my desktop to my iPod touch.

However at my house the simplest solution I have found is to use an Airport Express. I use iTunes to manage my music and then choose to play it on the Airport Express which is connected to my stereo in the living room. I can then use my iPod touch as a remote for iTunes to control what plays.

Comment: simplifymedia looks great, but they withdrew their iPod App from the store on March 12th! Looks like they're working towards launching something new ...

Comment: aaaaaand now they've been bought by Google. If someone has this solution, I'd be curious to hear it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [wifi2hifi](http://www.wifi2hifi.com/) app to stream any audio from your Mac but not on your PC to your iOS device.