# Make iOS 6 device (iPod Touch) DLNA renderer

Tags: ios, ipod-touch, streaming

We got an unused, semi-broken iPod Touch lying around. I would like to make it a DLNA renderer, so i can stream music TO the iPod, which is connected to the Audio-Amp. People often get the terminology for DLNA wrong, a DLNA Client is NOT what i am looking for. It is quite difficult to search for an App on iOS that actually receives DLNA streams: At least i couldnt find one.

I want the iPod to appear on my Network as a renderer and be able to play music using DLNA on it. AirPlay is not an alternative since i don't use other iOS devices.

And no, this is not a duplicate to my question...
[Can I stream music from my laptop to my iPod Touch over wifi?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/6811/can-i-stream-music-from-my-laptop-to-my-ipod-touch-over-wifi)
...since there is no DLNA solution mentioned.

AirPlayer seems to be a DLNA Renderer but needs iOS 7.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, found it. Involves jailbreaking the ipod but to my surprise this has become totally trivial over the years.

So, if anyone needs a DLNA renderer, check out intelligentShare UPnP AV Renderer... So far works perfectly using BubbleUPnP on my Android Phone as Controller, playing from my music library on a NAS running twonkyserver!